# Cannot create a 1D Texture on DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx-11

For some reason, the code below crashes when I try to create the 1d texture.

```
D3D11_TEXTURE1D_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE1D_DESC));
desc.Width = 64;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SNORM;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;

HRESULT hr = D3DDev_0001->CreateTexture1D(&desc, NULL, &texture); //crashes here
assert(hr == S_OK);
```

where D3DDev_0001 is a ID3D11Device. I am able to create 3d and 2d textures, but making a 1d texture causes the program to crash. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Don't use asserts to check HRESULTs, and definitely don't use equality tests. Use the ``SUCCEEDED`` or ``FAILED`` macros. As noted in the other answer, the reason for this failure would have been reported by the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) if you had enabled it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A USAGE_STAGING texture can't have any BindFlags since it can't be set on the graphics context for use as an SRV, UAV or RTV. Set BindFlags to 0 if you want a STAGING texture, or set the Usage to D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT if you just want a 'normal' texture that can be bound to the context.

USAGE_STAGING resources are either for the CPU to fill in with data before being copied to a USAGE_DEFAULT resource, or, they're the destination for GPU copies to get data from the GPU back to the CPU.

The exact cause of this error would have been explained in a message printed by ["D3D11's Debug Layer"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584(v=vs.85).aspx); use it to find the cause of these errors in the future.

Comment: Setting BindFlags to 0 did not solve the issue. Also I need USAGE_STAGING because I am programmatically filling in data from the CPU. I tried setting the debug layer, but all I get are info messages (no errors or warnings). Since my environment is not Visual Studio, I am getting the logs messages using DebugView.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. I was trying to deference a null ptr earlier in the code! I guess I'll mark your's as the answer because its the only answer haha.